# How to modify this script to search for multiple keywords?

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to modify a script. It is being difficult for me so I came for help. This script is supposed to extract data from some `.out` files and then write them in a `.txt`file. The problem is that I have two different keywords to look for. So, I provide the script, the things I am not able to modify and then two examples of input files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8

#~ Data analysis
import glob, subprocess, shutil, os, math
from funciones import *
for namefile in glob.glob("*.mol2"):
    lstmol2 = []
    lstG=[]
    os.chdir("some_directory")
    searchprocess="grep -i -H 'CURRENT VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION =' *.out | sort -k 4 > firstfile.txt" 
#~I need also to look for 'CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION ='
    os.system(searchprocess)

    fileout=open("results.txt","w")   
    filein=open("firstfile.txt", "r")
    #~ write data in results.txt
    fileout.write('\t %s \n' %("  HOF"))

    for line in filein:
        linediv=line.split()
        HOF=float(linediv[8])

  #~or [10] (for the keyword in need to add) but in both cases I need the float. I need both data of the keywords be included on this file.
        lstG.append(HOF)  
     fileout.close()  
    filein.close()
```

Input data, type 1:

```
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoo
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoov
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoo
CURRENT VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION = 1928
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoo
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoov
```

Input data, type 2:

```
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoo
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoov
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoo
CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION = 1930
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoo
foofoofooofoofoofoofoofoov
```

Comment: To me it seems like modifying the line with `HOF=float(linediv[8])` to `linediv[-1]` should work, seeing as its always the last part of the line.

Comment: thanks..@PrestonHager but how can I look for both keywords? I mean `CURRENT VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION =` and `CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `grep` command to look for the optional word with the `?` operator. Use the `-E` flag to enable exteneded regular expressions so you don't have to escape your regex operators. Always use single quotes around your pattern:

```
searchprocess="grep -E -i -H 'CURRENT( BEST)? VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION =' *.out | sort -k 4 > firstfile.txt"
```

@PrestonHager is correct that you should change `linediv[8]` to `linediv[-1]`, since in the cases where BEST is present, the number will be in the `linediv[9]` position, but in both cases `linediv[-1]` will give you the desired result.

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions to match patterns in the file, so you can use any of the normal regex operators to add the needed conditions to your pattern. Regular expressions can look very confusing and daunting to people who are not used to them, but they follow a very clear set of rules. Learn what the operators are then think through what pattern you need to match, and you will be able to figure out what operators to use. There are many regex tutorials available online, like this one: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html